# using a variable to define elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My function uses two variables which I define in my input-tag

```
function insert(aTag, eTag) {
 var input = document.forms['form'].elements['textarea'];
 input.focus();
...
}
```

...

```
<input type="button" name="bold" value="bold" onClick="insert('<b>', '</b>')">
```

The function will place the aTag and the eTag around selected parts in the textarea.
As I want to use this function in other textareas in the same form, I tried to use another variable in this function. This unfortunatly doesn't work.

I tried a lot of variants. Concept about like here:

```
function insert(aTag, eTag, selectInput) {
 var input = document.forms['form'].elements[selectInput];
```

...

```
<input type="button" name="bold" value="bold" onClick="insert('<b>', '</b>', 'thistextarea')">
```

Comment: Mixing html and js is a bad practice. Try using javascript event listeners like document.querySelector('input[name="bold"]').addEventListener('click', function() {...}, false);

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. You don't show what those `b` tags are used for, and I'm not sure what you mean by "selected tags in the textarea." A textarea contains text, not HTML - perhaps you mean your textareas contain unparsed HTML, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onClick handler, `this` refers to the object that was clicked. So you can simply do:

```
<input type="button" name="bold" value="bold" onClick="insert('<b>', '</b>', this)">
```

The function would receive the object without re-selecting it from anywhere:

```
function insert(aTag, eTag, input) {
    input.focus();
    ...
}
```

---

Side note: unobtrusive event handlers are preferred to inline.